# Как закачать df в ms sql БД, ошибка с rid, python/pandas/sql-server

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, sql-server, pandas

У меня выходит ошибка из-за отсутствия rid:

```
    pyodbc.IntegrityError: ('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
     Server]Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rid', table 'БД.dbo.таблица'; column does 
    not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) (SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft]
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
```

**Как решить данную проблему, rid он же по-идее сам должен генерироваться?**

Comment: Чтобы он сам генерировался его надо описать в таблице правильным образом. Как у вас таблица создаётся?

Comment: У меня она создается из read_excel,  потом некоторые столбцы переименовываются, датафрейм несколько раз копируется и в последующих копиях некоторые столбцы удаляются

Comment: Да нет, я про таблицу `БД.dbo.таблица`, как там описан столбец `rid`?

Comment: я не знаю, как посмотреть сейчас. можно я вам завтра отвечу

Comment: Как вам будет угодно. Просто ошибка `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rid'` говорит нам, что это видимо обычная колонка, причём `NOT NULL`. Она не описана как identity с autoincrement.

Comment: аа, я тогда завтра уточню на работе

Comment: На этот вопрос трудно дать ответ не видя `CREATE TABLE [таблица] ...` SQL команды - дополните пожалуйста вопрос... Возможно также понадобится небольшой пример данных для `df` фрейма

Comment: Что-то вы ещё меньше инфы в вопросе оставили. Параметры таблицы в базе посмотрели?

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо вам за совет, который вы мне дали вчера в комментариях он мне помог решить проблему. Проблема была с sql, а не с python. Я за ваш комментарий проголосовала.